# AS3 Store location of user uploaded image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to save the file path/url of what is loaded by the user to a string so it can be saved to an xml file (which I already have setup). When I load the string from the xml I want it to find the image again and load it back into the `selectedUpload` movieclip.

I think I know how to load an image from a URL but my problem is with capturing the URL into a string to begin with.

How would I do this?

My load image code:

```
var loadFileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
btnBrowse.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, loadImage);
function loadImage(e:MouseEvent):void{
    fts.hideHandlers();
    loadFileRef.browse([new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.png")]);
    loadFileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectedFile);
}
function selectedFile(e:Event):void{
    loadFileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeLoadImage);
    loadFileRef.load();
    loadFileRef.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectedFile);
}
function completeLoadImage(e:Event):void{
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
myLoader.loadBytes(e.target.data);
selectedUpload.addChild(myLoader);
loadFileRef.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeLoadImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileReference` doesn't give you the full file path for security reasons (I'm not sure they ever explained why).

I may be getting this wrong, but if you want to access the user file from the server, you first need to upload the entire file. In this case having the full path is unnecessary anyway.

Comment: It's only going to be used locally. Could I copy the image to the root (next to the flash exe file) and then refer to it from there somehow? I basically just want the image to be loaded back in when I load contents of the xml.

Comment: Unless you are using Air, I don't think so. Accessing the hard drive is way too dangerous for random applications. Sorry, but I can't think of a way to do that.